# jQuery UI accordion not working when data is refreshed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have an HTML page in which data is being dynamically loaded into accordions. The accordion call is happening from inside a function. This function is being called at regular intervals to refresh the data. The accordion is showing correctly the first time, but getting destroyed when the data is refreshed. Here is some relevant code:

HTML:

```
...

    <div id="itemsList"></div>

...
```

JavaScript:

```
function updateList() {
    var storedStates = startSpinner(spinner, 'itemsList');

    $.post('interface/getitemss.php', 
        function(data) {

            var dataObj = $.parseJSON(data);

            if(dataObj.status == 0) {
                var itemDetails = dataObj['data'];

                $("#itemsList").html("");
                var infoLevel = getInfoLevel();

                for (var i = 0; i < itemsDetails.length; i++) {

                    var rowContent = "<h3>";
                    if (item.type == 3 && item.approvals > 0) {
                        rowContent += "<span class='" + qaprColor + "'>";
                        rowContent += "<i class='icon-bell'></i>" + space + item.approvals + "</span>" + pipespace;
                    }
                    ...
                    rowContent += "</div>";
                    $("#itemsList").append(rowContent);
                } 
                $("#itemsList").accordion();
```

else in the code, I am using this:

```
var intervalTimer = setInterval(function() {updateList();}, <?php echo $interval; ?>);
```

This called the updateList() method regularly to update the data. The problem is, the moment this method is called, the previously-working accordion is destroyed and the data are appearing like normal HTML. Does anyone know how this could be fixed? Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried calling destroy on the accordion before creating it again?

```
$("#itemsList").accordion( "destroy" );
$("#itemsList").accordion();
```

found in [api docs](http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#method-destroy)